# Is a function that maps circles to circles necessarily a Möbius transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, circles, mobius-transformation

I'm introducing myself to Complex analysis and Möbius transformations and I read that Möbius transformations map circles and lines to circles and lines.

Are there any other functions that are not Möbius transformations but they can map circles to circles?

If I know that $f(z)$ maps a circle to another circle, can I assume that $f(z)$ is a Möbius transformation?

Comment: What if $f$ is not continuous? I'm sure you can find some counterexample.

Comment: $f(z)=\overline{z}$

Comment: @sometempname That's an answer. =)

Comment: Do you require that *every* circle maps to a circle, or just that there exists one circle that is mapped to a circle?

Comment: @mrf the latter one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on sometempname's comment: if $f(z)=\overline{z}$, then for the circle $|z-a|=r$, we have $$|f(z)-\overline{a}|=r,$$ so the image of a circle is a circle. Similarly, the image of a line is a line, so this will have the desired property but not be a Mobius transform.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you talk about analytic maps.  But even then you may take products of Möbius transformations which also maps $S^1=\{|z|=1\}$  to itself (1-1). Such transformations are called:
[Blaschke products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product)

If you do not require 1-1 then you also have maps like $z\mapsto z^p$ and if you  require analyticity only in a neighborhood of $S^1$ there are many more.

On the other hand a map that always maps any circle or line to a circle or a line is either a Möbius transformation (whence meromorphic) or a Möbius transformation composed with complex conjugation. Perhaps this is more what you are after... (and a proof is not that difficult)

Comment: $z^2$ maps the circle $|z-1|=1$ to a cardioid.

Comment: True, I only considered the last question and thought of the standard unit circle.