# Is a rational function which maps all circles/lines to circles/lines a Möbius transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

It is well-known that [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) map circles and lines to circles and lines. (Here and in the following, “line” means a line in the extended complex plane $\hat{\Bbb C}$, including the point at infinity.)

My question is if that property *characterizes* Möbius transformations, i.e. if the following converse statement is true:

> Let $f$ be a rational function which maps circles and lines to circles and lines. Then $f$ is a Möbius transformation.

Just to be clear: The property is that if $C$ is a circle or a line then $f(C)$ is also a circle or a line. If we consider $f$ as a mapping of the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) onto itself then it means that circles on the sphere are mapped to circles.

##### Context

In a [now deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1743607/42969) the following was asked:

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on the extended complex plane which is analytic except possibly at one point and maps lines and circles to lines and circles. Does it follow that $f$ is necessarily a Möbius transformation?

It is not difficult to see that under those conditions, $f$ has a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) at the possible exception point, so that it is analytic in all of the extended complex plane, and therefore a rational function. That leads to the above question.

This is posted as a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) because I figured out a solution which seems not to be posted before. Of course other answers are most welcome.

A previous related questions is [Is a function that maps circles to circles necessarily a Möbius transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1899329/42969)
 where the following examples are given:

- a [finite Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Finite_Blaschke_products) maps the unit circle onto itself.
- The functions $z \mapsto z^p$ map all lines through the origin to lines, and all circles with center at the origin to circles.

That are not counterexamples to the above conjecture because not *all* circles and lines are mapped to circles and lines.

Comment: This is a dupe of a question that was asked many times. It's even true for local  bijections, no need to assume rationality.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I *did* search for duplicates, perhaps not well enough. Do you have some links?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102187/automorphism-of-riemann-sphere/4102674#4102674 is asking about homeomorphisms, but the proof given by Coxeter is local.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thank you for the reference, I had not seen that before. I think it does no harm to have another Q&A with an explicit proof.

Comment: Yes, it is useful to have an easier proof in this special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is necessarily injective - let us use the same setup you have provided, namely assume that $f(\infty)=\infty$ and $f(0)$ is a simple zero. We now take $z_1,z_2\in f^{-1}(w)$ and form great circles $L_1,L_2$ that pass through $0,z_1,\infty$ and $0,z_2,\infty$ resp. Clearly $f(L_1),f(L_2)$ are the same great circles that pass through $0,w,\infty$, however that contradicts angle preservation at $0$. Thus $f$ has at worst a simple pole and a simple zero, for otherwise injectivity of $f$ and $1/f$ would be violated. The rest is clear.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the conjecture is true. A rational function which maps circles and lines to circles and lines is necessarily a Möbius transformation.

For the proof we can without loss of generality assume that $f(\infty) = \infty$ and that $f$ has a simple zero at $z=0$. (Otherwise consider $\tilde f = T \circ f \circ S$ with suitably chosen Möbius transformations $T$ and $S$.) Then every line through the origin is mapped to another line through the origin.

Choose two lines $l_1, l_2$ through the origin and let $L_1, L_2$ be the corresponding images. The angle between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is the same as the angle between $l_1$ and $l_2$ (here we use that $f$ has a *simple* zero, so that it preserves angles locally). Let us denote that angle between the lines with $\alpha$.

If we denote the reflection at the lines $l_1, l_2, L_1, L_2$ with $r_1, r_2, R_1, R_2$ respectively, then the Schwarz reflection principle tells us that
$$
  f \circ r_j = R_j \circ f \, , \, j=1, 2 
$$
and therefore
$$
 f \circ r_1 \circ r_2 = R_1 \circ R_2 \circ f \, .
$$
But the composition of reflections at intersecting lines is a rotation, and it follows  that
$$
 f(e^{i2\alpha} z) = e^{i2\alpha} f(z) \, .
$$
This holds for all $z$ and all real $\alpha$. Substituting this in the power series $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ at the origin gives
$$
 a_n (e^{i2n\alpha} - e^{i2\alpha}) = 0
$$
for all $n \ge 1$. If we choose $\alpha$ such that $e^{i2\alpha}$ is *not* a root of unity then $a_n = 0$ for $n \ge 2$ follows.

We have therefore shown that $f$ (after some composition with Möbius transformation) is a linear function, and that concludes the proof.

Comment: +1. Thanks for picking up the question and providing a  solution.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Consider $f$ is holomorphic around $z=0$, with $z=0$ zero of order $k> 1$. Consider two small circles passing through $z_0 =0$ and another point $z_1$, and forming a small angle $\alpha$. Then their images have angle $k \alpha$ at $f(z_0) =0$, but angle $\alpha$ at $f(z_1)$, so they cannot be circles.